# First time running a ASP site, and getting server error in '/' Application

Tags: asp.net

> [HttpException (0x80004005): Request is not available in this context]
>   System.Web.HttpContext.get_Request() +11207688
>   Slingshot.Engine.ApplicationBase.Initialize() +72
>   Slingshot.Engine.ApplicationBase.Application_Start(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +51
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Request is not available in this context]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +4185553
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +205
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +350
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +382
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Request is not available in this context]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11335894
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +88
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +4355316

Anyone have a clue where I could start?

Its also my first time running a local IIS web app. Is there things I haven't installed yet? I'm just not sure what these errors mean or where I could get started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you see you get 3 times the same error, one say Slingshot.Engine, that means all your starting modules have the same problem.

This is means that you run IIS7 on  Integrated pipeline. **For start you can turn it to Classic mode**, to let the site run, and later change your application code to not use the request context at `Application_start`

If you absolute need to use the context first time you run your application, [make a one time Initialize](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/11/10/Integrated-mode-Request-is-not-available-in-this-context-in-Application_5F00_Start.aspx) at the `Application_BeginRequest` that have the context.

Comment: IIS 6 management compatibility is one thing I haven't turned on. Could this be a problem? Looking into turning on Classic Mode.

Comment: @Tom Locate the pool that you use for your site, and change it to classic mode. If you use it for more than one sites then is better to make a new pool to avoid other conflicts.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! This is pretty interesting stuff. I should consider getting some basic knowledge into asp.net programming.

Answer (score 4):

You are executing some code that requires the request object in your application start event and that cannot be done because the application is started before the request is handled. Put the code that needs the request in your begin request event.